# Counterexamples of Annihilator in Infinite Dimensional Setting

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Is there a simple example of an infinite dimensional vector space such that $(W_1\cap W_2)^\circ \not= W_1^\circ +W_2^\circ$?

Comment: What do you mean by an annihilator?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples: Why did you add this tag? This wasn't the question, it seems to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space Just search up annihilator.

Comment: @Asaf Because the proof of the equality requires Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: So what? You're also using sets here, why not add [set-theory] too? Or [logic] since you are inferring things?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand your comment. This result depends on the axion of choice. Useful to be noticed no?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Yes, but the tag itself is aimed for questions which specifically deal with the use of the axiom of choice. Not just noting that something requires the axiom. The fact it requires the axiom is interesting, and a useful piece of information to add to your answer, yes. But the tag is irrelevant here.

Comment: OK. Understand.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. If $E$ is a vector space and $W_1,W_2$ vector subspaces of $E$ then you have $$(W_1\cap W_2)^\circ = W_1^\circ +W_2^\circ.$$ This is true even if $E$ is of infinite dimension. However, Axiom of Choice is required in that case to work with basis.

Comment: So it is always true that $(W_1\cap W_2)^\circ \subseteq W_1^\circ +W_2^\circ$ in the infinite dimensional case? Could you give a sketch of the proof in this instance?

Comment: That is in French https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~rombaldi/AgregInterne/Oral1/109.pdf. However if you look at "Remarque 12.5 point 3., that can be (hopefully!) readable.

Comment: mathcounterexamples.net's reference is now https://web.archive.org/web/20131126042254/https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~rombaldi/AgregInterne/Oral1/109.pdf  It uses ⊥ instead of ∘; see Définition 12.4.